# jquery tabs default tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jQuery tables on my webpage:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
            ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. " +
                    "We'll try to fix this as soon as possible");
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>                     

<div id="tabs">  
    <ul>    
        <li><a href="location.php">Name1</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.php">Name2</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.php">Name3</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.php">Name4</a></li> 
        <li><a href="location.php">Name5</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.php">Name6</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.php">Name7</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.php">Name8</a></li>
        <li><a href="log.php">Name9</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I set default Name (table) on this script?  Because this should work but nothing:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({active: 2});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function() {    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({active : 5},{ beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {       ui.jqXHR.error(function() 
  {          ui.panel.html(     
         "Couldn't load this tab. " +  
                   "We'll try to fix this as soon as possible" );        });      }    });  
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add divs for each href and href should contain id of div. Following is the example

```
<div id="tabs">  
  <ul>    
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Name1</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the API documentation.  There is a good working example there.

http://nshra006.am.ds.rd.honda.com/staging/hra/hrao/isd/is1/webdocui.nsf/CatalogWebHome?readform&section=home

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu,</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, d.</p>
</div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est </p>
    <p>Duis cursus. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the structure above contains a *ul* tag which creates your tabs.  It requires and expects the subsequent *div* tags which must have id's matching the hrefs in the anchor tags.

So href="#tabs-1" is linked directly to div id="tabs-1" in this way.